# Reducing SetPass calls and batches in Unity

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, shader

I'm creating low poly assets for my game and I'm trying to make them as optimized as possible. From what I have learned best way to do it is to use one material for as many objects as possible. Since for my assets I use one color per face I created 8x8 pixels texture and used it as a palette - each pixel has different color(mapped UVs of every model to correct colors). After doing this the number of SetPass calls was always the same no matter how many of these objects i had. I thought its alright but then i read [this](http://www.pencilsquaregames.com/2015/01/reducing-draw-calls-also-named-setpass-calls-on-unity5/) article and now I'm a little bit confused. When he did same thing as I did - used one material for whole scene his batches and SetPass calls whent to 1. Now I wonder why in my scene they are higher. Shouldn't they be 1 as well? Aleso I'm using Mobile/Diffuse shader, but I think this shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I think you should read this article too. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html - Maybe you should apply your game dynamic and static batching rules. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html. I hope you can find the solution in these articles.